# Eclipse:Run on server option not visible for maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm running through the jboss as7 getting started guide here http://hudson.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS7-Docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/guides/developer-getting-started-guide/target/docbook/publish/en-US/html/helloworld.html .   The tutorial has us setting up an example helloworld quickstart maven project.

I'm able to deploy this project from the command line successfully

```
mvn package jboss-as:deploy
```

but when I attempt to deploy the helloworld example from Eclipse - the 'run on server' option is missing from the run menu.  I have Eclipse 3.7 and maven wtp installed.

Not sure how to fix, any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 33):

The `run on server` related options only appears if your project has the `Dynamic Web Moudle` project facets.

You can try to configure it using the `Project Facets` options in your project properties

[image]

Comment: thanks! it works for me. why this answer is not accepted yet?

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm still getting an error: `The selection cannot be run on any server`

Comment: for my project when I am running with Run as maven install after that war is running successfully fine but when i am running Run as Server its giving me HTTP Status 404

Answer (score 7):

To help any other developer with this problem.

I was dealing with this issue recently. Maven projects are structured differently than Dynamic Web Projects. So when you manually add the Dynamic Web Module using Project Facets, eclipse may not register it properly as a Maven project.

To solve this, you have to install the **m2e plugin** and **M2E Eclipse WTP plugin** (this tells Eclipse how to run your maven projects).

Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace to search for the plugins.

After installing, you will need to restart Eclipse then you will be able to use "run on server" for your Maven projects.

*Note*: You may need to remove/delete the previous project then import/create it again after the restart.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add maven eclipse pluginin your pom.xml file..

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Red Hat's site, The M2E Eclipse WTP plugin (m2eclipse-wtp)  has been deprecated in favor of the newer m2e-wtp plugin.  If you don't want to go through the marketplace, the URL for the new plugin is http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the project and refreshing it, closing and reopening it, removing and re-adding it (right-click on server) and updating Maven... the option reappeared. 
I think it occurs when you up the version of the Java compiler in your .pom file, when you up the compiler in project properties or it has to do with using the newer Jersey (2) version or when you both include local libraries and maven dependencies, it may also be a consequence of a combination of these. It's pretty unclear.
Note though, that you can still add/remove projects by right-clicking on the server in the servers tab.